# Use Java class of project in Gradle - Android Studio

Tags: android, class, android-studio, build, gradle

Is it possible to use a class of my Android Project with plain Java code in my Gradle build script without making a jar with that class and loading it in my project gradle file?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you properlly - Yes. You have some different options:

1. To make another build which to produce a jar and to make `buildscript` dependency in you build.gradle file.
2. Create build script and put your java class directly. I offer you to use `apply from: "lib/gradle/buildscript.gradle"`